# Download file from Google Drive and upload to S3 using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, google-drive-api

I download my PDF file from Google drive according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads):

```js
const file = await this.driveClient.files.get(
  {
    fileId: id,
    alt: 'media',
  },
  {
    responseType: 'stream'
  },
);
```

Then I construct a form data:

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file.data, 'file.pdf');
```

And send it to S3 via the [presigned upload url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html):

```js
const uploadedDocument = await axios({
  method: 'put',
  url: presignedS3Url,
  data: formData,
  headers: formData.getHeaders(),
});
```

The flow works, but the file uploaded to s3 appears corrupted:
[image]

I also tried different response types from Google API such as `blob`. Any idea what I am missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by piping the file `stream` from `google drive` directly to `s3` using `nodejs` built-in packages.

```js
import * as https from 'https';
import { promisify } from 'util';
import { pipeline } from 'stream';

//...

const file = await this.driveClient.files.get(
  {
    fileId: id,
    alt: 'media',
  },
  {
    responseType: 'stream'
  },
);

await promisify(pipeline)(
  file.data,
  https.request(s3SignedUrl, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'content-type': fileMetadata.mimeType,
      'content-length': fileMetadata.size,
    },
    timeout: 60000,
  }),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the file as PDF from google drive, use the following function, passing the id:

```
/**
 * Download a Document file in PDF format
 * @param{string} fileId file ID
 * @return{obj} file status
 * */
async function exportPdf(fileId) {
  const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
  const {google} = require('googleapis');

  // Get credentials and build service
  // TODO (developer) - Use appropriate auth mechanism for your app
  const auth = new GoogleAuth({scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'});
  const service = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});

  try {
    const result = await service.files.export({
      fileId: fileId,
      mimeType: 'application/pdf',
    });
    console.log(result.status);
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Comment: `Export` method throws the `Export only supports Docs Editors files.` error, so I have to use `get` method